# Android Test stopping in instantiating tests

Tags: android-testing

When i run my `ui` test, it just stopping in instantiating tests...

Uploading file:

```
local path: /Users/eclo/AndroidStudioProjects/Minicooper4android/Minicooper4android/app/build/outputs/apk/NAMmogujie714-uiTest-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.mogujie.test
```

No apk changes detected. Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead.

```
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am force-stop com.mogujie.test
```

Running tests

What's wrong?