# android tests often stall at 'instantiating tests'

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

When I click the run test button, Android Studio builds and attempts to run the test.

70% of the time, it says "Instantiating tests..." and never goes anywhere from there. If I kill the adb-server, unplug adevice, or kill an emulator, the test suite magically runs fine.

I even saw a bizarre behavior the other night. I unplugged the device while it said Instantiating Tests. Android Studio picked up that it disappeared. I pulled my phone out of my pocket a few hours later, unlocked it, and out of nowhere, it started running the test suite.

Any idea what can cause this behavior? The closest I've found is [Android Test stopping in instantiating tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468259/android-test-stopping-in-instantiating-tests), but that is referring to a different issue.

Comment: Was this resolved?

Comment: no :( I've partially switched to using Genymotion, which helps some, but I have tests that require VPN, so it doesn't solve my problems.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: still no solution, no

Comment: Try to debug individual test case and see. May be it started but due to some UI blockers like Progress Dialog it may not be able to run further

Comment: For me this connected to a device, when I run it on an Samsung Galaxy S8, everything works, on my brand new OnePlus 5 they are just never starting.

Comment: Try cleaning the project once.

Comment: I can't believe we just accept gradle as it is. A computer can perform millions of operations per seconds and gradle is stuck in a single tasks for a good 6 minutes to run one tests. What they are doing under the hoods It's beyond my understanding

Answer (score 9):

I had the same, issue would only occur when running as debug though. Never had it when running normally.

I fixed it by removing Test Orchestrator in my Build.gradle.

```
//Disable Me
//        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
//        testOptions {
//            execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
//        }
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Anyone know why the new test orchestrator won't run in debug mode?

Comment: @eliasbagley  it was a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/78658117  , hopefully fixed now.

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me on my `OnePlus 5` as well - I couldn't make it running. Seems like it's related to this device only.

I end up using an emulator and other phones, which works fine.

Comment: I also tested this on OnePlus 5. It stays stuck on Instantiating. Works fine on emulator though. I couldn't test this on any other device. Seems like a device specific issue.

Comment: Same to me, with a OnePlus 5T. Unbelievable

Comment: same with my oneplus 5 also

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same - the test runner starts, says "Instantiating tests" but then nothing happens.

As hinted by Sumukh Bhandarkar's comment above, I did the following:

- Build > Clean Project
- Debug test again

If this doesn't work, and you have Android Device Monitor open:

- kill the process marked with a red 'debug' symbol
- Debug test again

If *this* doesn't work, and you still have Android Device Monitor open:

- close Android Device Monitor
- Debug test again

Answer (score 1):

I tried Artie's suggestions but they didn't work for me. In the end what worked was:

1. Close emulator
2. Open AVD Manager
3. In the Actions column, click on the downward-pointing arrow and choose "Cold Boot Now"
4. Wait until the emulator is running again
5. Run the tests

After doing that the tests built pretty fast and ran without problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Things that have caused this for me:

- I had my build configuration set to "All in package," and had set the Package Name to just com.mycompany. Changed to com.mycompany.appname to fix the problem.
- Emulator being out of date. Running update fixed issue.

Comment: Creating a new virtual device and running on there worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your test in different ways. Everything worked for me only when I called the test from the context menu of the folder where the test file is located. This is probably due to the fact that the plugin has not been updated for a long time, and now launching by clicking on the file or on the launch icon in the file itself does not work.